# How do I move one column up in a two column bootstrap layout?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, background-image

I have two column Bootstrap layout with a header image on top.

```
<section class="header" style="background: url(header-image.jpg)"></section>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 sectionOne">
            <p>some long text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 sectionTwo">
            <form>My form here</form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I bring the right column up (`class= "sectionTwo"`), to cover the header background image (see below)?

```
   ----------------
  |                |
  |  header image  |
  |        --------|
  |-------|        |
  |       |   2    |
  |   1   |        |
  |       |--------|
  |       |        |
   ----------------
```

I tried CSS relative positioning on the parent with `position: absolute` & `top: -100px`, on the child, but that cause bootstrap to produce a non responsive design.

Comment: I want on mobile to see 'sectionTwo' separate, the same as now.

Comment: I didn't plan to add it.

Comment: You can just add negative margin to the `sectionTwo` class but on smaller devices its will go over the `sectionOne` class instead so you will need to check for the breakpoint and remove the margin

Comment: For mobile screens (sm and xs) do you want the `sectionOne` and `sectionTwo` to appear one after the other or do you want the to remain side by side like you've drawn above?

Comment: one after the other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This **code** may help you to achieve the **Responsive layout** you want:

```css
.header{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100px;
 background: yellow;
}

.flexWrapper{
 display: flex;
}

.sectionOne{
 width: 50%;
 height: 200px;
 background: violet;
}

.sectionTwo{
 height: 200px;
 width: 50%;
 background: #3498DB;
 transform: translateY(-40px);
}
```

```html
<div class="header">Header Image here</div>
<div class="flexWrapper">
  <div class="sectionOne">section 1</div>
  <div class="sectionTwo">section 2</div>
</div>
```

You can change the Transform and other properties according to your need. You don't have to use Bootstrap for this kind of layout.

Comment: Bootstrap is required to make it responsive, that is to adapt to mobile screens.

Comment: This Flex code will be responsive on Mobile screens.

Comment: You can use bootstrap for section content management and for other purposes if you want.